# Completely reset a single service in Docker Compose, including deleting the volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to recreate a service, including its volumes. The closest I got was the following commands:

```
docker-compose stop foo
docker-compose rm -f foo
docker-compose up --renew-anon-volumes -d foo
docker-compose start foo
```

The issue here is `--renew-anon-volumes` recreates all services that have anonymous volumes, not just `foo`'s volumes. If I don't use `--renew-anon-volumes`, then I think I need a named volume to do `docker volume rm myvolume`. However, with named volumes, Docker Compose always prepends a project name. Since my script doesn't know the project name, I can't programmatically delete the volume. I can't enforce that the user uses a particular project name. I know I can set the project name using an environment variable, but there's no guarantee that the user won't run Docker Compose with a different project name.

I think there are 2 potential solutions:

1. Make `--renew-anon-volumes` only recreate the volumes for the service I specified
2. Use a named volume and somehow figure out the correct prefix

Are either of these doable, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many roads leading to Rome, depending on your prerequisites:

1. Do `docker volume ls` and regex the result for your named volume (just working if volume name is unique)
2. Use `external` volumes and `volume create` them with known names by bootstrap script before running `docker-compose up` (not working if volumes must be instantiated)
3. Set project name to a known value. Normally it takes the folder name, but can explicitly given in `docker-compose` command (`-p NAME`) or by environment variable (`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=NAME`).
4. Setup a dummy compose-file just containing this single service with its volumes for your script. Doing a `docker-compose -f 'your-down-file.yml' down -v` which removes all named and anonymous volumes belonging to this service and `docker-compose -f .. up` on this file.

**Edit (@DavidMaze):**

You're right, docker compose recognizes that fact. But it does NOT remove it, just warning. If you want to remove all "orphans" you need the flag `--remove-orphans`.
But for some reasons the down does not remove volumes then, even if flag `-v` is given. This could be reported because it is not behaving like described.

And errata: the flag `-f` must go before up/down and not after!

Comment: (I think for the last option, there's some risk that Compose will see that the other containers aren't listed in `your-down-file.yml` and decide they must have been intentionally removed, so it will delete the other containers too.  It's worth testing this out before writing a script around it.)

Answer (score 1):

[`docker-compose rm`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/) has a `-v` option to delete anonymous volumes attached to a container, and also a `-s` option to stop the container.  For your particular use case it should be enough to:

```sh
docker-compose rm -s -f -v foo
docker-compose up -d foo
```

This will only help for anonymous volumes, that is, where the Compose file has `volumes:` with only a container path and there is no corresponding top-level `volumes:` entry.  I don't immediately see a Compose option to list, remove, or otherwise manage named volumes that Compose created.

Comment: `-v` doesn't work for me, I read in another SO answer that it works for `docker-compose down`, but not `rm`

Comment: If you're in the same directory as a `docker-compose.yml` I assume that `docker compose rm -v` does the same as the above. `docker-compose` no longer exists. `docker compose` now does the same thing as `docker-compose` used to. Can't be 100% sure however as I am just learning how to use both Kafka and Docker.